# Native Library Usage Issues in React Native

Tags: react-native, mobile, charts

I’m attempting to use the victory-native library to create a chart, but it’s not functioning as expected. Here’s the code I’m using:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import Title from "../components/title";
import TabBar from "../components/tabBar";
import { VictoryPie, VictoryLabel } from 'victory-native';
import * as Svg from "react-native-svg";

const Intercorrencias = () => {
  return (
    <View className="flex-1 space-y-10 bg-white pr-7 pl-7 justify-between">
      <View tw="mb-20">
        <Title text1="Intercorrências" />
      </View>

      <View tw="flex-1 justify-center">
        <View
          tw=" bg-white rounded justify-center p-5"
          style={styles.cardShadow}
        >
          <View tw="items-center">
            <Svg viewBox="0 0 400 400">
              <VictoryPie
                standalone={false}
                width={400}
                height={400}
                data={[
                  { x: "A", y: 40 },
                  { x: "B", y: 16 },
                  { x: "C", y: 33 },
                  { x: "D", y: 5 },
                ]}
                innerRadius={110}
                labelRadius={100}
                style={{
                  labels: { fontSize: 20, fill: "white" },
                  data: {
                    strokeLinecap: "round",
                    fill: ({ datum }) => {
                      if (datum.x === "A") return "#6FAAF8";
                      if (datum.x === "B") return "#6497DA";
                      if (datum.x === "C") return "#3632ED";
                      if (datum.x === "D") return "#194395";
                    },
                  },
                }}
                labels={() => null}
              />
              <VictoryLabel
                textAnchor="middle"
                verticalAnchor="middle"
                x={200}
                y={200}
                style={{ fontSize: 23, fontFamily: "Poppins_400Regular" }}
                text="Intercorrências"
              />
              <VictoryLabel
                textAnchor="middle"
                verticalAnchor="middle"
                x={200}
                y={230}
                style={{ fontSize: 25, fontFamily: "Poppins_500Medium" }}
                text="0"
              />
            </Svg>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>

      <TabBar />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  cardShadow: {
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 3 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 3,
    elevation: 4,
  },
});

export default Intercorrencias;
```

Additionally, here’s what came within the library:

```
`/**
 * Cartesian chart exports (including useful types)
 */
export { CartesianChart } from "./cartesian/CartesianChart";
export { type InputDatum, type CartesianChartRenderArg, type ChartBounds, type YAxisSide, type XAxisSide, type PointsArray, type Scale, type MaybeNumber, } from "./types";
export { type CurveType } from "./cartesian/utils/curves";
export { type RoundedCorners } from "./utils/createRoundedRectPath";
export { useAnimatedPath } from "./hooks/useAnimatedPath";
export { AnimatedPath } from "./cartesian/components/AnimatedPath";
export { usePrevious } from "./utils/usePrevious";
export { useChartPressState, type ChartPressState, } from "./cartesian/hooks/useChartPressState";
export { useLinePath } from "./cartesian/hooks/useLinePath";
export { Line } from "./cartesian/components/Line";
export { useBarPath } from "./cartesian/hooks/useBarPath";
export { Bar } from "./cartesian/components/Bar";
export { useBarGroupPaths } from "./cartesian/hooks/useBarGroupPaths";
export { BarGroup } from "./cartesian/components/BarGroup";
export { useAreaPath } from "./cartesian/hooks/useAreaPath";
export { Area } from "./cartesian/components/Area";
export { Scatter, type ScatterShape } from "./cartesian/components/Scatter";
export { CartesianAxis } from "./cartesian/components/CartesianAxis";
`
```

I tried to implement a graph using the victory-native library in a React Native project. I expected the chart to render correctly. However, the library isn't working as expected, and I can't find the chart I want.

Comment: Just add height & width to Svg component it will work